# how to git push to a local branch?

Tags: git

I git clone a project on my computer and have a local master branch, let say A. Here, I create some local branches (let say B and C).

I made some changes in B and C. So, how do I can git push to merge the changes in B and C to A?

Normally, I see that

```
 git push origin master
```

to push to the remote repository, but I want to push to a local branch.

Thanks

Comment: Have you give this a shot  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651985/git-merge-with-repository-on-local-filesystem

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `git merge` instead to manipulate local branches.

```
git checkout master
git merge B
git merge C
```

If you really want to push a local branch to another local branch, `git push . B:master`, though this is quite rare.

Comment: Love the answer, pushing to another local branch is exactly what I needed for my script!

Answer (score 2):

While on the master branch, have you tried

```
git merge B
```

This should merge your local branch B back into master, same can be done for branch C

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 2):

As others said, normally you want to switch to *A* and then merge from *B* instead.

However, if you do it regularly, in some edge cases it makes sense to set *A* as upstream branch for *B*

```
git checkout B
git branch --set-upstream-to A
# shorthand: git branch -u A
```

and then use *git push* from branch *B* like you asked.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to merge branch A to B

First commit your changes, if you have done any changes and want that changes to be merged to B branch

`git add --file path--`  : adds files to stage and then

`git commit -m "add commit msg"`

and then `git checkout B`, you will be now in B branch.

`git merge --no-ff A` (we are doing non fast forward merge, merging branch A into B branch)