# Push commits to local branch only not remote

Tags: git, version-control

I have a project on bitbucket the I cloned locally. when I checkout a branch to work on a feature I want my commits to be available on the local feature branch ONLY then when everything is good to go, push all commits from local branch to remote one.

Currently when I push commits to the local branch using `git push` git always complains about this push, shows a `use git push --set-upstream <remote branch>` and exits.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `push` always updates the remote refs. If you want your changes on the local branch only, all you got to do is to checkout the local branch and `commit` your changes.

Comment: In the terminology of git, "push commits to the local branch" doesn't make any sense. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: My previous answer may help, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38868412/6330106. For local branches, `git merge`, `git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` are more suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don't need to push. When you commit your code it stores your updated code locally and will not send it to any remote.